# Understanding spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d, spherical-coordinates

Let Σ be the unit upper hemisphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, $z ≥ 0$.
Calculate Integral $z^4 dA$.

I know z would be $cos(phi)$, but why is $dA=sin(phi) d(theta) d(phi)$? is it being the derivative of z a coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parameterization $r(\theta, \varphi)$ for your surface, then $dA$ is given by 
$$\Vert r_\theta \times r_\varphi\Vert \,d \theta d\varphi$$
Here, $r = \langle \cos \theta \sin \varphi, \sin \theta \sin \varphi, \cos \varphi \rangle $, and the above formula gives us $dA = \sin \varphi\, d\varphi d\theta$. The similarity between $dA$ and the derivative of $z$ is a coincidence, in that it does not hold for other situations.

Comment: how did you come to the conclusion that   r=⟨cosθsinφ,sinθsinφ,cosφ⟩?

Comment: It's spherical coordinates with $\rho = 1$, and so that function parameterizes the sphere with radius $1$. There are, of course, other valid parameterizations, which will give you different values for $dA$ (but the same final answer).

Comment: is r(theta) the derivative of r with respect to theta?

Comment: Yes, same with $r_\varphi$.